# will document ids like {year}-Q{n} cause performance problems?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [Firestore docs "Best Practices" section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) says:

> Document IDs
>
> Do not use monotonically increasing document IDs such as:
>
> `Customer1`, `Customer2`, `Customer3`, ...
>
> `Product 1`, `Product 2`, `Product 3`, ...

I'd like to store historical data in a collection with one document per quarter, and use document ids like `2022-Q1`, `2022-Q2`, etc.

These aren't strictly monotonically increasing because the year number changes after 4 quarters. But they're still lexicographically close. Will this cause performance problems?

My data goes back about 50 years so there will be around 200 documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 documents with *any* IDs are not going to cause any performance problems.  That is a very small amount of data from Firestore's point of view.

The recommendation that you're citing from the docs has to do with situations where documents are added very rapidly to a collection.  If you read on, it says "Such sequential IDs can lead to [hotspots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#hotspots) that impact latency".  If you read about hotspotting, that is not your situation, so you don't have to worry about it.

Aside, it's generally not a good idea to put data in your document IDs.  That can cause problems for you later.  Data belongs in document fields.  You're generally better off using Firestore's randomly generated IDs unless you already have a source of unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason I'd want to use the quarter as the document ID is to make it easier to add data to docs. E.g. I can do `doc('.../2022-Q1').set({...}, {merge:true})`. When using randomly generated IDs, I'd have to first run a query and then add data, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you would have to query for the document first in order to update it.  But for only 200 documents, it is still super cheap.  But as long as you are committed to those IDs and will never change them, you should be OK.  You can't retroactively change a document ID without copying the entire document and writing it with a new ID, and deleting the original.